# Echo equivalent in PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I want to start a program that prompts the user for an input like below.

How would I do this?

My question is  : what would be the PowerShell equivalent to the following code?

```
(echo input1 && echo input2) | program.exe
```

Comment: For those who may not be aware of the idea of the batch file, when program.exe runs, the end user is prompted for two inputs, this method sequentially automates each of those interactive inputs.

Comment: `'input1', 'input2' | program.exe`

Comment: `echo $input1 $input2 | program.exe`, echo being an alias for write-output.  You can shorten that to `$input1,$input2 | program.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

echo just displays the next bit of text on the screen, PowerShell equivalent:

```
Write-Host input1 input2
```

Calling a program is as easy as:

```
notepad.exe
```

Please advise if I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to prompt user you may use: `Read-Host`
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/read-host?view=powershell-6

If you would like to print to the console, you may use `Write-Host`
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host?view=powershell-6
but it shows the output only to the console!!

If you would like to pipe it, you may consider `Write-Output`: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output?view=powershell-6

Hope it helps!